# Using join on multiply tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Im trying to join 3 tables together using left join.

My problem is that I dont get the right join for my query.

- The number of return rows is different.
- The count is not correct.

If I run this I get correct join and more than 1 row.

```
SELECT classes.name, trainers.trainer_name trainerName

FROM gym_classes classes

left join gym_tainer_rel trainers

on

classes.teacher = trainers.id
```

But If I try this query:

```
    SELECT classes.name, trainers.trainer_name trainerName, count(usersInClass.user_name) as sum

    FROM gym_classes classes

   left join gym_tainer_rel trainers

    on

    classes.teacher = trainers.id

    left join class_user_rel usersInClass

    on

    usersInClass.class_id = classes.id
```

I get only 1 row back and the count is not correct.

Comment: use group by classes.name and count(distinct usersInClass.user_name)

Comment: Don't you use an aggregate function in order to use your `count()` ? I think you're only showing us part of the query, and the problem may be  in the part we don't see...